# ViewController not showing up...Xcode iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

so I have an iPhone game that I am trying to add a main menu too. But I can't get the main menu to show up...attached is a screenshot of what my storyboard looks like.

However when I click run instead of showing the main menu, it just proceeds to the game.

Any help is appreciated...also I didn't know what parts of my code I would need to post so if you need to see code to help just ask and I'll post it.

Here is the screen shot: [image]

Comment: Can you post the code of your main menu view controller? So I can help you

Comment: I cannot get the code tags to work on this forum so it won't let me post any code, however I posted it here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1614379  thanks for helping!

Comment: no init method for your view controller?

Comment: how do I add an init method?

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard seems ok, and first view Controller set is your ViewController1. So, i suggest you to force the root view controller at the AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
  ViewController1 * mainviewController= [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
  [self.window addSubview:mainviewController.view];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
  }